# disable emails on cpanel

Tags: email, cpanel, whm

Does anyone know how I disable emails for an account on Cpanel? They host their own emails but we host their site and currently, every time we try to mail them, it just stays within the server and doesn't get to them.

I used to use Plesk and it was as easy as flicking a switch to turn emails off but I can't see that in cPanel. I've tried setting their package to 0 emails in WHM but I'm suspecting that's not going to work.

-James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the domain example.com **are pointed** to your DNS

login to WHM and go to Main >> DNS Functions >> Edit MX Entry for the example.com

and when Edit the example.com choose  "Remote Mail Exchanger" this will Configure server to not accept mail locally and send mail to the lowest MX record.

so double check the example.com MX records to make sure the MX records set to the valid Mail Server.

if example.com **are NOT pointed to your dns** and just use IP forwarding to run on your server you can remove the dns entry for example.com by delete the dns zone for example.com as it not used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send mails from same cpanel server where the website hosted then mail server trying to resovle that domain locally. check the domain entry in /etc/localdomains and remove  or comment that entry and you can add that domain in /etc/remotedomains.